# How to print Hindi text using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, multilingual

I want to print some paragraphs using Window Forms that will be static but when I click on print it generated the pdf with blank text, please help me out here, there is no table, no grid, simple paragraph.
I'm using ItextSharp to print the pdf file.
Please help how to print in Hindi.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir") + @"\fonts\Kruti_Dev.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        Document document = new Document();
        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("राम ");
        var paragraph=  Convert.ToString(para);
        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(12, paragraph, font));
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("D:/a.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        document.Open();
        document.Add(para);
        document.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is fairly common to have Indic fonts that are not Unicode compatible.  Like this one, it maps ASCII codes to Hindi glyphs.  There is no practical way to use it, translating all text to ASCII is very little joy.  Use another one.

Comment: also, not sure what type of Paragraph you are using but are you sure it support/overrides the ToString method? Otherwise Convert.ToString(para) is not going to give you what you expect.